# How to detect standby event from Messenger?

Tags: messenger, dialogflow-es

Using Messenger Handover protocol I can pass the control to inbox when user requests to talk to a human. I want the bot to listen on standby in order to take the control back when user requests it. The problem seems that the bot doesn't listen on standby.
My Facebook page is subscribed to Standby event and Webhooks integration is enabled in my Messenger app. In DialogFlow the Facebook Messenger integration is set. In the fulfillment code I don't receive requests after handing the conversation thread control over to inbox.
Please help!

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or set of instructions?

Comment: No tutorial. I'm looking at the documentation in dialogflow and messenger SDK.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't any tutorials on this particular use case. It seems DialogFlow simply doesn't listen to those events. I'm currently trying to solve this very same problem, I'll update you if I'm able to find anything useful!

Comment: Do we have any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for this, but actually I'm not sure if it wil work, I'll just post it to see if anyone maybe has tried it.
I think you should create an own webhook, this is going to be subscribed in the Facebook App Messenger Webhook in Facebook Developers Portal.
You will have to set your this webhook to receive all the corresponding events from Facebook, like 'messaging', 'standby, 'messaging_handovers', etc (currently 'messaging' event is used to send the messages from users, and 'messaging_handovers' and 'standby' are used to switch control from bot (DialogFlow in your case) to another app (could be inbox page).
Then, you will have to set up your webhook, depending on the callback received, like this:
 - If request_thread_control callback is send: the webhook should send a pass_thread_control to the second reciver 
- you will have to set up a protocol to activate take_thread_control, to return the ownership of the conversation to the bot
- In any other callbacks (asuming the rest are for the messages send to the bot), the webhook should send them to Dialogflow using a client of it inside your webhook, evaluating if the bot has the ownership of the conversation or another app has (again could be another app or inbox)
As I said, it's just an idea, I'm not sure if it will work. Hope it helps somone!

References:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/pass-thread-control (Passing Thread Control to the Page Inbox (Live Chat))
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/request-thread-control#page_inbox (Requesting Thread Control From the Page Inbox)

*This is an idea to make passing the ownership avoiding to create an intent that do that. Specially if you want to switch between bot and inbox page just moving a conversation from Done to Inbox or from Inbox to Done

Comment: Thanks for the idea, a derivative of it worked. The solution for me was to create another bot like you said, subscribe to the webhook, assign it as the secondary bot under "Secondary Receiver for Handover Protocol" in page settings, and then upon the call of some specified keyword like "bot back" post pass_thread_control to the primary (dialogflow) bot. However, this is needlessly complex, it would be ideal if dialogflow supported facebook standby or standby in general until it is called back. I'd love to know if there has been any other solutions to this as well.